# AutoPwn suite both the keyword and keyword exact match capabilities of the vulnerability search page and APIs, any alternative?

Tags: security, public, scanning, soc

I've been using AutoPwn in our SOC, and it's been a while since the vulnerability scan stopped working for these public URLs: https://services.nvd.nist.gov/rest/json/cves/1.0 and https://services.nvd.nist.gov/rest/json/cves/2.0. As far as I understood, the issue is caused by the fact that the NVD has been experiencing problems with website and API availability. While they're handling this problem, they've disabled both the keyword and keyword exact match capabilities of the vulnerability search page and APIs.

So, I was wondering if anyone is facing the same issue and if you managed to find an alternative to bypass this problem?

Any help would be much appreciated.